# Loading a ResourceDictionary from IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm attempting to download a file, 'theme.xaml', from my webservice and add it to the App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.  The trouble I'm having is I don't know how to create a ResourceDictionary from a file in IsolatedStorage, where I'm caching it.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
        ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();
        rd.Source = new (Uri("isostore:/theme.xaml"));
        App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
```

But I get an  "Unspecified Error" on the call that sets the source.  I'm pretty sure I can't address islolated storage in the Uri this way.  But what is the right way to do this?

Comment: can you post the exact error message you are getting..?\

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your code should be something more on the lines of 
would also need to see what the config xml looks like too

```
 ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();
 rd.Source = new Uri("/isostore;/theme.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
 App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
```

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't work.  The Uri blows up with lots errors:
theme
{isostore;/theme-2123418883.xml}
    AbsolutePath: 'theme.AbsolutePath' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    AbsoluteUri: 'theme.AbsoluteUri' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("theme.xaml", FileMode.Open, storage))
    {
        var xaml = XElement.Load(stream);
    }
}
```

Try if you can get this to work.
I have used this approach to load xmlfiles.
Think you can use `Application.GetResourceStream` instead of `XElement.Load()`